# Pandas parse text column

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv, parsing

I have a csv table with a column that contains the text from a chat log. Each text row follows the same format of **the name of the person and time of the message (with an additional front and back space padding) followed by the message content**. An example of a single row of the text column:

```
'  Siri (3:15pm)  Hello how can I help you?  John Wayne (3:17pm)  what day of the week is today  Siri (3:18pm)  it is Monday.'
```

I would like to transform this single string column, into multiple columns (number of columns would depend on number of messages), with one column for each individual message like below:

- `Siri (3:15pm) Hello how can I help you`
- `John Wayne (3:17pm) what day of the week is today`
- `Siri (3:18pm) it is Monday`

How can I parse this text in a pandas dataframe column to separate the chat logs into individual message columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this dataframe:

```
                                                                                                                     Messages
0  Siri (3:15pm)  Hello how can I help you?  John Wayne (3:17pm)  what day of the week is today  Siri (3:18pm)  it is Monday.
```

then you can do:

```py
x = df["Messages"].str.split(r"\s{2,}").explode()

out = (x[::2] + " " + x[1::2]).to_frame()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                                            Messages
0            Siri (3:15pm) Hello how can I help you?
0  John Wayne (3:17pm) what day of the week is today
0                        Siri (3:18pm) it is Monday.
```

Note: *It only works if there 2+ spaces between the Name and Text.*

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, took me a while but we got to it!

```
s = pd.Series(['  Siri (3:15pm)  Hello how can I help you?  John Wayne (3:17pm)  what day of the week is today  Siri (3:18pm)  it is Monday.'])
s = s.str.split(r"  ", expand=True)
s = s.drop(labels=[0], axis=1)
s = s.transpose()

for i in s.index:
    list_1 = list(s[0])

odd_i = []
even_i = []
for i in range(0, len(list_1)):
    if i % 2:
        even_i.append(list_1[i])
    else :
        odd_i.append(list_1[i])

d = {'Name': odd_i, 'Message': even_i}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

Output:
                   Name                               Message
0         Siri (3:15pm)             Hello how can I help you?
1   John Wayne (3:17pm)         what day of the week is today
2         Siri (3:18pm)                         it is Monday.
```